# Storing data across multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I am making an ajax call to get all the images in the database.
For each of the image id returned I call an ajax function to get the thumbnail for the image.

I have two arrays *img_arr,src_arr*. *img_arr* stores the data returned by first ajax call and *src_arr* stores the data of the second ajax call.

```
var img_arr=[],src_arr=[];
function get_all_images(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get_all_images/',
        success: function(data){
            parsedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(parsedData.length!=0){
                for(var i =0;i<parsedData.length;++i){
                    img_arr.push(parsedData[i]);
                    // console.log(img_arr.length);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'get_thumb/'+parsedData[i],
                        success: function(data){
                            src_arr.push(data);
                            //console.log(src_arr.length);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
    console.log(img_arr.length);
    console.log(src_arr.length);
}
```

However at the end when I get 0 for both the array lengths.  But when I print the lengths within the success callback of ajax I get proper length of the arrays. Is there a way to store and use the data after the success callback?

Comment: Not sure I get it, are you using an ajax GET request to get images ?

Answer (score 0):

That'll be a lot of server-side calls,

just an idea : why don't you just get the all the images with their associated thumbnails on the server and then just make one ajax call to get your images+thumbs back ?

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the last line of your code, with the console.log, none of those ajax calls have returned, yet.  That's why the arrays all have zero length.  Your success function is a callback, which means that code doesn't run until the ajax call goes out to the server and then the server has sent its response back to the browser.  Meanwhile, your code doesn't wait, it continues on.  So it has sent out a bunch of requests, but almost certainly it hits the console.log line before any of them have come back (unless there are hundreds or thousands of requests).

In any case, I agree with the previous poster that you should try to bundle these up rather than make a bunch of little requests.  Your server will thank you as you start to put load on it.